# Ionic Vue build app without devDependencies

Tags: docker, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

I want to build an ionic vue app with docker. Since I want the docker image to be as small as possible, I want to skip devDependencies. The problem then is, that the `npm run serve` or `npm run build` command rely on `vue-cli-service`, which is a devDependency by default (when using ionic cli to setup the project).

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "3.2.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.2.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "3.2.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.2",
    "@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^5.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.2.0",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.9.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.27.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "cypress": "^9.0.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.0",
    "cypress-localstorage-commands": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.9.0",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "prettier": "2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.35.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.12.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^21.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  },
}
```

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:lts-slim as build-stage

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Is it possible to build without the devDependencies or maybe delete the dependencies after building?

Comment: The Dockerfile you show already in effect deletes the dependencies after building: it uses a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to build an image based on an Nginx server with only the built `dist` tree, but no Node or `node_modules` directory at all.  (The final `EXPOSE` and `CMD` are redundant with the base `nginx` image and it's safe to remove them.)

Comment: you're right, so I just had to remove the ENV NODE_ENV=production and RUN npm ci to RUN npm install, many thanks!